# Launching Sonic Pi automatically from Command Line on Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, linux, raspberry-pi

I need to launch Sonic Pi automatically from the command line when the Raspberry Pi starts. 
How can:
1) I get rid of the username/password prompt when the raspberry Pi launches?
2) Automatically launch sonic pi?
3)Automatically launch a Python script that I have written (that needs to communicate with Sonic Pi?)

Comment: Why don't use nongui script on startup (if not create a music box)?

Comment: How would I do that?

Comment: Give me  time, need tested on my PI.

Answer (score -1):

Connect PI via Putty or sshclient(linux).
Get an mp3 on web : wget "mp3 url" 
Or put file with filezilla (client) to PI (/home/pi/)
***Filezilla settings = 
server:sftp://pi@your_pi_ip_adres 
username: pi
password: raspberry
port:21***

Than:
omxplayer -o hdmi where_mp3_dir_and_name #play on hdmi port(ON TV or ETC)

omxplayer -o local where_mp3_dir_and_name #play on audio jack.

if want to automate it put your script /etc/init.d/ and ***update-rc.d your_script_name default*** [`update-rc.d manual`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man8/update-rc.d.8.html)

But need testing your script for bugs before adding to system startup.
[read more](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/usage/audio/)